# how to retrieve table rows into dialog box and edit

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have jquery like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
function fnOpenNormalDialog() {
            $("#dialog-editTweet").html("Tweet Edit Box");

            // Define the Dialog and its properties.
            $("#dialog-editTweet").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                title: "Modal",
                height: 250,
                width: 400,
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        callback(true);
                    },
                        "No": function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        callback(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        $('.btnOpenDialog').click(fnOpenNormalDialog);

        function callback(value) {
            if (value) {
                alert("Tweet Edited");
            } else {
                alert("Rejected");
            }
        }


    });
```

I have table like this

```
<fieldset id ="allTweets">

            <table cellspacing="20" class ="tweetTable"  >
            <caption>Tweets</caption>
    <%


        while(rs.next()){
    %>
            <tr id="ForChangingTweet">
                <td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>               
                <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="btnOpenDialog" value="Edit Tweet" /></td>
                <div id="dialog-editTweet"></div>

            </tr>

    <%
        }
    %>
        </table>
        </fieldset>
    <%
```

Now i want to edit the dialog box as form so that when i will click 'edit tweet' button it should immediately retrieve the last two  and i will edit the middle  in the dialog box.I want to use ajax in my jquery which will send last  and edited middle  to servlet and based on the value of last  i will modify the database. I cannot change the last  because it is timestamp value. please tell also how to use ajax which will call servlet to change into database. I am very new in jquery.

Comment: Your edit tweet dialog button doesn't work it seems.

Comment: Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinoth_Krishnan/nnv64/).

Answer (score 0):

You were raising this question **multiple times**. Don't do like that. To add value to your question try to *concise the text and clearly post what you were tried* and where you are stuck? And of course *provide if you have enough bounty* to get solve this fast.

By the way i am posting **half of the solution** for you. Till editing the table values on click the button. Please find the code for getting table values in modal. In scripting,

```
 $("#firstTextBox").val($(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(1)').text());
 $("#secondTextBox").val($(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(2)').text());
 $("#thirdTextBox").val($(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(3)').text());
```

Slight modification in your HTML,

```
<div id="dialog-editTweet" style="display:none;">
    Name:  <input type="text" id="firstTextBox" name="firstTextBox" /><br>
    Age: <input type="text" id="secondTextBox" name="secondTextBox" /><br>
    Subject: <input type="text" id="thirdTextBox" name="thirdTextBox" /><br>
</div>
```

From this you need to send an ajax request to update the edited values into DB.

Here is working ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinoth_Krishnan/nnv64/16/)***

**PS:** Use the hidden Id to update the rows. Hope this will give starting point. Cheers..